# Get input checkbox values in php after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have search a lot but couldn't apply any answer to my problem.

I have a form generated by php. The form result is like this:

```
<form class="add-item">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="cust[]">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="cust[]">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="cust[]">
  <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="cust[]">
  <button class="submit"> 
</form>
```

This form can have 4 inputs or 20, depend the product.

So now I want to send the checked boxes to php through ajax. For this reason I have tried this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    url: "testing_cart.php",
    type: 'POST', 
    data: 'cust='+$('.add-item input[name="cust[]"]').serialize()+'', 
    success: function(data){
        alert(data); // to see what is going on in php
    },
    error: function(){
       alert('dio error');
       } 
 });
$.ajax();
```

In my PHP file I have only this:

```
$cust = $_POST['cust'];
print_r($cust);// to see what ajax send
```

In some way this code is working but not as I am expecting.

If I check the only one checkbok I get this result:

```
cust[]='1' // the value of the checked checkbox
```

and if I check more than 1 I get an array but this array ignores the first item on the list... for example the code below is if I check all the checkbox... as you can see the first input is ignored:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2 // the value of the checked checkbox
    [1] => 3 // the value of the checked checkbox
    [2] => 4 // the value of the checked checkbox
)
```

I want to get an array always (if is possible) so if I the customer will select only 1 I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2 // the value of the checked checkbox
)
```

And if the customer select more well, all the values in an array.

Any idea?

p.s. sorry if my code vocabulary is not the best

Comment: Why don't you iterate nodelist and send `JSON` over php ?

Comment: have a look on this http://jsfiddle.net/ex36m0uf/1/
this is hint for you

Comment: thanks for your help guys, I am going to use the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is more simple.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.add-item').submit(function (event) {
                var data = $('.add-item').serialize(); // send all the form data
                console.log(data); // for debug only
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'form_ajax.php',
                    data: data,
                }).done(function (data) {
                    console.log(data); // response from server via ajax
                });
                event.preventDefault(); // prevent submit
            });
        });
```

With this manner you send all the form. Nothing changes even if you send 1 or 20 values.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is with your `data` statement.  `.serialize()` returns a string containing the input field names followed by their value.  Your `data` statement forms this string `cust=cust[]=1&cust[]=2&cust[]=3&cust[]=4` (when all check boxes are selected).  This (and I'm really just guessing here) first allocates the array `cust[]` to the variable `cust` (the `=1` is dropped as it is invalid in a query string) then starts assigning values to that array.  Which is why you are only getting the last three values.

To fix your problem you could change your `data` declaration to -

```
data: $('.add-item input[name="cust[]"]').serialize(),
```

and also change your php `$cust` declaration to -

```
$cust = $_POST['cust[]'];
```

If that is valid in php. (I have very little experience php).

The below demonstrates what your `serialize` statement is creating -

```js
$("#serialise").click(function() {
  $("#result").text(unescape('cust=' + $('.add-item input[name="cust[]"]').serialize() + ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="add-item">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="cust[]">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="cust[]">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="cust[]">
  <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="cust[]">
  <button id="serialise" class="submit">Serialise</button>
</form>
<div id=result "></div>
```